# Function to load data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I created a function to load data from MySQL using VB.NET however I have received the following error:

> Fill : la propriété SelectCommand.Connection n'a pas été initialisée.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

This is my code:

```
Private Sub ShowDataExam(ByVal DGV As DataGridView, ByVal TBL As String, ByVal CNN As MySqlConnection )
    OpenConnexion()
    Using DA As New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" & TBL & "]", CNN)
        Dim DTEL As New DataTable
        DA.Fill(DTEL)
        DGV.Font = New Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Bold)
        DGV.DataSource = DTEL
        CloseConnexion()
    End Using
End Sub
```

And this how to use it:

```
ShowDataExam(DataGridView1,"examiners",DataConnexion.Conn)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your code as :

```
Private Sub ShowDataExam(ByVal DGV As DataGridView, ByVal TBL As String, ByVal CNN As MySqlConnection )
    OpenConnexion() 
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [" & TBL & "]", CNN)
    Dim DA As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    DA.SelectCommand = cmd
    Dim DTEL As New DataTable
    DA.Fill(DTEL)
    DGV.Font = New Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Bold)
    DGV.DataSource = DTEL
    CloseConnexion()
```

Comment: im using vb.net not c sharp

Comment: Jinx88909 you have right i have edit the answer thanks

Comment: @Jinx88909 i have no message how ask me to accept an edit !

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure *why exactly* you are passing through your `DataGridView` as a parameter however consider changing it to [ByRef](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c84t73c2.aspx):

> Specifies that an argument is passed in such a way that the called procedure can change the value of a variable underlying the argument in the calling code.

`ByRef` differs slightly from [ByVal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h2b185t2.aspx):

> Specifies that an argument is passed in such a way that the called procedure or property cannot change the value of a variable underlying the argument in the calling code.

This may not actually be an issue if the method is within the form that the `DGV` resides on however then you don't need to pass it as a parameter. Like I said I'm not sure *why* it is you're passing it as a parameter.

As for the error you are getting (translated to English):

> The SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized.

I would consider a slight change to your code as I feel in this case you don't actually *need* a `MySqlDataAdapter`, instead use [MySqlCommand](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/html/T_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlCommand.htm):

```
OpenConnexion()
Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [" & TBL & "]", CNN)
    Dim DTEL As New DataTable
    DTEL.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)

    DGV.Font = New Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Bold)
    DGV.DataSource = DTEL

    CloseConnexion()
End Using
```